# Selenium grid tests with TestNG - multiple tests on multiple machines

Tags: testng, selenium-grid

we have a running selenium grid setup. Before the grid, when I started the tests with the suite parameter parallel="tests" it would start several browser instances on the same machine. Now that I've set up the grid, it only starts one test per machine. How can I change it, so that more tests per machine are started?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run multiple RCs per node in the grid.  The current structure of grid is such that only one session may be run on an RC at a time.  I'm hoping to change this, but that's the state of the system as of 1.0.8.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact I just went ahead and tried starting a couple of RCs on my slaves each with a different port and it works fine.